# A sufficient condition for convergence of objective functions evaluated at a minima.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, optimization, uniform-convergence, equicontinuity

My question is whether the following argument is correct. Is there any defect on my proof?

Let $f_n$ and $f$ be  real-valued functions defined on a metric space $(S,\rho)$ such that $f_n \to f$ point-wise.
Suppose that $f_n$ and $f$ are minimized at $x_n^*$ and $x^*$, respectively.

I wish to derive a sufficient condition for the convergence
\begin{eqnarray}
f_n(x_n^*) \to f(x^*)
\end{eqnarray}
as $n\to \infty$. To this end, first observe that
\begin{eqnarray}
|f_n(x_n^*) - f(x^*)| &\leq& |f_n(x_n^*) - f(x_n^*)| +f(x_n^*) - f(x^*)\\
&\leq& 2  |f_n(x_n^*) - f(x_n^*)| +|f_n(x^*) - f(x^*)|.
\end{eqnarray}
By point-wise convergence, the second term on the right converges to $0$.

To show the convergence of the first term on the right, let $A := \{x_n^*: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then,
\begin{eqnarray}
 |f_n(x_n^*) - f(x_n^*)| \leq \sup_{x\in A} |f_n(x) - f(x)|.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus,by a standard argument for uniform convergence, I conclude that the following conditions are sufficient for the convergence  $f_n(x_n^*) \to f(x^*)$:

(a) $A$ is relatively compact,
(b) $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ and
(c) the family $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous on $A$.

As Matt A Pelto suggested, the condition (b) can be deleted since uniform equi-continuity of $\{f_n\}$ and point-wise convergence $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ imply uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: At most finitely many members of $\{f_n\}$ cannot be continuous. The infinitely many continuous members of $\{f_n\}$ must form an equicontinuous family on a set $A \subset S$ such that $x^* \in \text{int}(A)$. I also assume that $(S, \rho)$ is separable. Pretty sure this is a double implication. The converse is very reminiscent of problem 1.6.10 from 'Berkley Problems in Mathematics'. Because of the way this forum works (forum's fault, not mine), I am still mulling over whether I want to code an argument.

Comment: Also, I am pretty certain that strengthening your assumption from equicontinuous on $A$ to uniformly equicontinuous will allow you to not require $x \in \text{int}(A)$. You don't need to explicitly require $f$ to be continuous.

Comment: Hopefully my comments are sufficiently helpful. Otherwise someone else is going to have to answer your question Yamamoto. Perhaps ask Hirak (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/166713/hirak) because the individual insists on wasting my time on this forum by rejecting helpful and insightful edits to this thread
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209417/limit-and-0-999-dots-1


The state of politics in the US makes me feel like I should speak up and insist that poor behavior not start prevailing on the math forum as well.

Comment: @Matt A Pelto   Thanks for your help. You mean that the condition (b) can be deleted because uniform equi-continuity of $\{f_n\}$ and point-wise convergence $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ imply uniform continuity of $f$. I will add your comment in the text.

Comment: Yes, because as the uniform limit it will inherit the eventual uniform continuity from the eventually uniformly equicontinuous family. I say eventually because that is what you can show going in the other direction. At least when you are merely given $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$ whenever $x_n \to x$ as in the aforementioned problem 1.6.10. This book that I mention is I think legally available for download in pdf if you search it. No solution is given but you could at least see the statement of the problem.